# Looking for PHP library to render cron expression verbally

Tags: php, cron

Can you please advice a **PHP library** or at least a **code snippet** to convert Cron expression string to a verbal statement?

For example:

```
"5 4 * * *" -> "At 04:05."
"5 4 * 2 SUN" -> "At 04:05 on Sunday in February."
```

Comment: it can be done with a java library

Comment: I love java, but it will be a bit of overhead to connect java library to PHP application :)

Comment: If you want to do it with php i cannot help you.. :/

Comment: maybe interesting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909244/how-to-use-java-from-php-5. Also: http://www.developer.com/java/other/php-with-java-using-php-java-bridge-tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you, @RyanVincent, it's an interesting read. I definitely have to try such integration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was not able to found such PHP library anywhere, I decided to create it myself: https://github.com/sivaschenko/utility-cron

Usage:

```
$expression = \Sivaschenko\Utility\Cron\ExpressionFactory::getExpression('5 4 8 * *');

echo $expression->getVerbalString(); // "At 04:05, on 8th day of month."
```